# send mail from depending on the selected user in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email

i have one selection form in my application..in that i get users list from the users table in the selection box drop down..i am trying to send mail depending on the selected user from drop down..
i got user_id from the drop down..but i didn't get email..i tried a lot but i didn't found where i got error..

Here is my controller:

public function add_selection()
{

```
$data["msg"]="";
 $this->load->model('SelectionModel');
$data['rolename']=$this->SelectionModel->getrolename();
$data['candidate']=$this->SelectionModel->getcandidates();
$data['usertype']=$this->SelectionModel->getusers();
```

if($this->input->post())

```
{

  $this->SelectionModel->add_selection_details($this->input->post());
 $all_users = $this->input->post('user_id');
 print_r($all_users);
       foreach($all_users as $key)
      {
         $get_email = $this->SelectionModel->get_user_email_by_id($key);

         $config = Array(
          'protocol' => 'smtp',
          'smtp_host' => 'ssl://md-in-42.webhostbox.net',
          'smtp_port' => 465,
          'smtp_user' => 'test3@clozloop.com',
          'smtp_pass' => 'test3'
      );
         $this->load->library('email',$config);
         $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
         $this->email->from('test3@clozloop.com', 'bharathi');
         $this->email->to($get_email); 
         $this->email->subject('this is our candidate details pls go through it');
         $link = 'Click on this link - <a href="http://localhost/job_portal/index.php/Login/signin">Click Here</a>';
         $this->email->message($link);
         print_r($get_email);
         if($this->email->send())
         {

              echo "email sent";
          }
          else
          {
              echo "email failed";
          }


}
```

}

```
$this->load->view('selection/selection_details',$data);
```

}

This is my model:

```
 function get_user_email_by_id($user_id)
```

{

```
$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->from('users'); 
$this->db->where('user_id',$user_id); 
$query = $this->db->get(); 
$result = $query->row_array();
return $result['email'];
```

}

please help me how to do this..
Thank you..

Comment: what is output on  `print_r($all_users);'?

Comment: it display user_id

Comment: i am trying to get that user_id email..but it's not working..

Comment: array of ids or only one single id?

Comment: it display only one single id..but i want arrays of id's..and it display in the users preview..but it's not stored in the database

Comment: are you getting proper email after calling model's method. `echo $get_email;` what is output?

Comment: it dosen't display anything...i didn't get mail

Comment: Do you need to get user wise email?

Comment: haa s.. i want to get that particular user email..to send mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model. Try once like this..

```
 function get_user_email_by_id($user_id) 
    {
    $this->db->select('email'); 
    $this->db->from('users'); 
    $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id); 
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    return $query->row()->email;
    }
```

In view:

```
<select class="form-control" multiple class="form-control" data-placeholder="user name" name="user_id[]" >
<?php foreach($usertype as $rows) { ?> 
<option value="<?php echo $rows->user_id?>"><?php echo ucfirst($rows->first_name)?></option> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Try edited answer for single user.You need  to show your view part for how you select multiuser in dropdown.

Comment: <select  class="form-control"  multiple class="form-control" data-placeholder="user name"  name="user_id" >
                                 
                                   <?php foreach($usertype as $rows) { ?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $rows->user_id?>"><?php echo ucfirst($rows->first_name)?></option>
                                 <?php } ?>

Comment: change `name="user_id[]"`.And try in the same way that you try in controller.

Comment: @M5533 glad to help you.Best of luck ahead.

Comment: can i use like this $list=array('nalamalapu.bharathi@gmail.com','bharathi.nalamalapu@gmail.com');$this->email->to($get_email,$list);

Comment: if `$list` is array pf person that you want to send mail.Then use `foreach` loop.

Comment: how can i use for loop for that one..please show me.

Comment: like this `foreach($list as $user){$this->email->to($user);}`. It sends mai to all users in array `$list`.

Comment: $this->load->library('email',$config);
             $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
             $this->email->from('test3@clozloop.com', 'bharathi');
             foreach($list as $user)
             {
              $list=array('nalamalapu.bharathi@gmail.com','bharathi.nalamalapu@gmail.com');
             }
             
             $this->email->to($get_email,$user);

Comment: change it `$this->email->to($get_email,$user)` to `$this->email->to($user)`

Comment: I think your controller code is perfect now.why you need to maintain array.Statically.

Comment: to send mail for more people at a time you can set`cc`,`bcc`.for more see here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: after `$this->email->to($get_email)`; try using `foreach($list as $user){$this->email->to($user);}`.But usibg cc,bcc is good way.

Answer (score 0):

try this get the values in an array through select while you're multiple selecting the values! name="select[]"

```
if(count($this->input->post()) > 0) {

  $this->SelectionModel->add_selection_details($this->input->post());
 $all_users = $this->input->post('user_id');
 print_r($all_users);
       foreach($all_users as $key)
      {
         $get_email = $this->SelectionModel->get_user_email_by_id($key);

         $config = Array(
          'protocol' => 'smtp',
          'smtp_host' => 'ssl://md-in-42.webhostbox.net',
          'smtp_port' => 465,
          'smtp_user' => 'test3@clozloop.com',
          'smtp_pass' => 'test3',
          'mailtype' => 'html',
          'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
          'wordwrap' => 'TRUE',
          'newline' => '\r\n'
      );
         $this->load->library('email',$config);
         $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
         $this->email->from('test3@clozloop.com', 'bharathi');
         $this->email->to($get_email); 
         $this->email->subject('this is our candidate details pls go through it');
         $link = 'Click on this link - <a href="http://localhost/job_portal/index.php/Login/signin">Click Here</a>';
         $this->email->message($link);
         print_r($get_email);
         if($this->email->send())
         {

              echo "email sent";
          }
          else
          {
              echo "email failed";
          }


}
}
```